# Write multiple summations in matrix form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, matrix-calculus, symmetric-functions

Let $Y=(y_{ij})_{n\times n}$ be a symmetric matrix with diagonal elements being $0$. Define the following quantity
\begin{equation}
V(y) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{\ell=1}^n y_{ij} y_{ik} y_{i\ell} y_{jk} y_{j\ell} y_{k\ell}. 
\end{equation}
How to write $V(y)$ in matrix form?

(ps: Using trace, sum of rows/columns of matrix, element-wise product of matrix $\textit{etc.}$ are allowed.)

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\dss{\mathop{\odot}\limits}
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\a{\;{\rm and}\;}\def\b{\beta}\def\g{\gamma}
\def\d{\delta}\def\t{\theta}
\def\l{\lambda}\def\s{\sigma}\def\e{\varepsilon}
\def\n{\nabla}\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\D{{\cal D}}\def\F{{\cal F}}\def\G{{\cal G}}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\vec#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\operatorname{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\hess#1#2#3{\frac{\p^2 #1}{\p #2\,\p #3}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\rc#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\bc#1{\color{blue}{#1}}
\def\gc#1{\color{green}{#1}}
$Define the $12^{th}$ order analog of the Kronecker delta symbol
$$\eqalign{
\D_{i\rc{j}w\bc{k}x\gc{\ell}\rc{m}\bc{p}\rc{n}\gc{r}\bc{q}\gc{s}} = \begin{cases}
\o 
\quad{\rm if}\;(i=w=x) \\
\qquad\a(\rc{j=m=n}) \\
\qquad\a(\bc{k=p=q}) \\
\qquad\a(\gc{\ell=r=s}) \\
0
\quad{\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
\\
}$$
and the sixth dyadic power of $Y$ as
$$\eqalign{
Y^{\star 6} &= Y\star Y\star Y\star Y\star Y\star Y \\
}$$
where $(\star)$ denotes the dyadic/tensor product.

Then the sum in question could be written as
$$\eqalign{
V
 &= \D \,:\,:\,:\,:\,:\,:\, Y^{\star 6} ​\\
 &= \D \;\dss^{12}\; Y^{\star 6}​\\
}$$
where the $12$ dots between the tensors denote contraction products.

Comment: Thank you very much!